# How to `@Autowired` a non Spring class or instantiated by new X()?

Tags: spring-mvc

I need to auto wire a @Service inside a javax.servlet.Filter.

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    AccessLogService accessLogService;

    public void setAccessLogService(AccessLogService accessLogService) {
        this.accessLogService = accessLogService;
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // save an access log to the database...

        AccessLogDTO rld = new AccessLogDTO( req );
        accessLogService.addAccessLog( rld );   // <<<--- NPE here! 

        // and do other stuff not related to the question...

    }

}
```

but I'm getting NullPointerException error.

```
@Service
public class AccessLogServiceImpl implements AccessLogService {
  // ordinary not special service class.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't use dependency injection from a filter directly. Although you are using GenericFilterBean your Servlet Filter is not managed by spring.

Please remove `@Autowired` .

```
AccessLogService accessLogService;
```

and instantiate your service class inside doFilter method.

```
if(accessLogService==null){
            ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
            WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
            service = webApplicationContext.getBean(AccessLogService.class);
        }
```

Comment: Great!! Good skill. Thanks!